# Selenium Java : Not able to Extract value from the div

Tags: selenium

//To find the path

```
  WebElement
  Xpath=D2.findElementByXPath("//[@id='main']/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/article/div/span");
```

// to extract value

```
 System.out.println(Xpath.getText());
```

I am expecting to get value as $239 but getting error " no such element"

Comment: <div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="place in filteredPlaces">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="max-height: 480px ">
<article class="box">
<figure>
<div class="details">
<span class="price1">
<small>from</small>
$239
</span>

Comment: u should keep HTML Code in that.

Comment: You should add the html to the question and not a comment. This is really not a angularjs question. More like a selenium question. For selenium it's much better to use id's than use some crazy xpath like that

Answer (score 0):

Ah... Seems like the api guide needs to be looked at. The call is:

```
WebElement we =   D2.findElement(By.xpath("path"));
// interact with element
we.text(); // or
we.click(); // or whatever else
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below  code  it should work for you

```
WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class ='price1']"));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```